# Minecraft PE Realms invalid name

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I have signed up with valid passwords and email address, but when I have to choose my name (even though I typed valid name, sticking with only letters) it keeps saying invalid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What name are you trying?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Minecraft Realms unless you were invited. You also can't uses <kbd>SPACE</kbd> either, because Usernames typically don't accept multiple words. For example, if you wanted **Minecraft God**, you'd do **Minecraft_God** or **MinecraftGod**. Numbers are also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft PE Realms is still in testing at the current moment. Unless you were invited to play you won't have access to the servers.

Comment: This is helping but not answering the question.